# Getting error "Running pass 'Module Verifier' on function.. " while archiving project

Tags: ios, swift

getting this only while archiving project it works before, don't know what causes this issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to fix by Changing Optimization Level to No Optimization

> Build setting -> Swift compiler - code generation -> Optimization Level -> **No Optimization**

[image]